# Successful test from OpenScript fails in Test Managger with “Find Object Timeout” error (Oracle)

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, oracle-ats, oracle-openscript, timeout

I am trying to execute in  Oracle's Test Manager, an automatic test which I created in Oracle's OpenScript.

My script in OpenScript is executed successfully as you can see below:

[image: OpenScript test execution]

---

When I execute the same test in Test Manager, I get a `Find Object timeout` . You can see below the error:

[image: Test Manager test execution]

---

Because of this error, I have added the following event in my OpenScript test case and tried to execute it again from Test Manager. The error persists; the only change is that the time before the timeout increased to 300.

```
        web.image(
            99,
            "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='Checkout | Test Store']/web:document[@index='0']/web:img[@index='4' or @src='http://duckshop.scl.intra/duckshop/cache/6e12ca9108aae3731f906138977ccac52f2a38b5320x320_fwb.png']")
            .waitFor(300);
    {
        think(3.056);
    }
```

---

Why do I get this error?

---

> UPDATE: As I have discovered only the first time the test is passed. I
> tried to use command line option while executing the test such as that
> no cookies will be stored or cache, but still I can't solve my
> problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the index attributes like `@index='0'` 
and
`waitForPage` statements might fail if the page is loaded faster then your script.

Use `waitForPage` with 2 parameters and 2nd parameter value to be true:

```
web.window( “/web:window[@title=’Google’]”).waitForPage(200,true);
```

OR Use:

```
web.window( “/web:window[@title=’Google’]”).waitForPage(PAGEWAIT,true);
```

where `PAGEWAIT` is a global variable maintained at master script level.